# Bank Application that Handles Exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I want to create a Banking Application that can handle errors and throw exceptions to handle does errors that occur. These are the Exceptions i want the program to handle :

1. Withdrawing more than the current balance from an account. This should print an error message.
2. Attempting a transaction (deposit, withdrawal, or balance) on an account that has not been created yet.
3. Trying to create more than the maximum number (19) of accounts.

Here is My Code :

using static System.Console;
namespace Bank
{
    public partial class Bank : Form
    {
        public Bank()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private int _nextIndex = 0;

    Accounts[] arrayAccounts = new Accounts[19];


    private void createAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIDTexTBox.Text)) return;
        var account = new Accounts();
        int accountID;
        int balance = 0;

        bool success = int.TryParse(accountIDTexTBox.Text, out accountID);


        if (!int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out balance))
        {
            result.Text = "Invalid Format in the Amount Fields please correct";
            //   MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format in the Amount Fields please correct");
        }


        if (balance < 300)
        {
            label5.Text = ("initial deposit must be $300 or greater");
        }

        else if (success)
        {
            account.AccountId = accountID;
            account.Balance = balance;
            arrayAccounts[_nextIndex] = account;
            OutPutLabel.Text = "Account # " + accountID + " open with balance of " + balance;
        }


        else
        {
            result.Text = ("invalid AccountID entered, Please Correct");
        }
    }

    private Accounts GetAccounts(int id)
    {

            return arrayAccounts.Where(x => x.AccountId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }


    private void DepositRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIDTexTBox.Text)) return;
        int amount = 0;
        int accountID;
        bool succcess1 = int.TryParse(accountIDTexTBox.Text, out accountID);
        bool success2 = int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount);
        try
        {
            if (succcess1 && success2 && amount > 0)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccounts(accountID);
                selectedAccount.Balance += amount;
                OutPutLabel.Text = "Account # " + accountID + " deposit " + amount;
            }
            else if (!succcess1)
            {
                result.Text = "You are attempting to deposit  to a non-number ID";
            }
            else if (!success2)
            {
                result.Text = "Youu are Attempting to deposit \n "+ 
                    "to a non_Number amount  \n Please reenter the amount";
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
            result.Text = "Account has not being Created , \n Please create an Account";
        }

    }

    private void WithdrawRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIDTexTBox.Text)) return;
        int amount = 0;
        int accountID;
        bool success1 = int.TryParse(accountIDTexTBox.Text, out accountID);

        bool success2 = int.TryParse(amountTextBox.Text, out amount);
        try
        {
            if (success1 && success2 && amount > 0)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccounts(accountID);
                selectedAccount.Balance -= amount;
                OutPutLabel.Text = amount + " withdraw from account # " + accountID;
            }


            else if (!success1)
        {
            result.Text = "You are attempting to withdraw from a non-number ID";
        }
        else if (!success2)
        {
            result.Text = "Youu are Attempting to Withdraw \n " +
                "a non_Number amount  \n Please reenter the amount";
        }

    }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            result.Text = "Account has not being created , \n Please Create Account";

        }

    }

    private void exceuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /// if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountIDTexTBox.Text)) return;
    }

    private void balanceRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int amount = 0;
        int accountID;
        bool success1 = int.TryParse(accountIDTexTBox.Text, out accountID);
        try
        {
            if (success1)
            {
                var selectedAccount = GetAccounts(accountID);
                OutPutLabel.Text = "Account # " + accountID + " has a balance of " + selectedAccount.Balance;
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            result.Text = "Account has not being Created"
                + "\n Please create account.";

        }
    }
}

class NegativeNumberException : Exception
{
    private static string msg = "The Amount you enter is a negative number";
    public NegativeNumberException() : base(msg)
    {
    }
}
```

I have being able to handle some of the errors using TryParse and If/else statements. Is there a better way to handle those errors using Exceptions.

here is the code for Account Class:

```
public class Accounts
{

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        Balance += amount;
    }

   public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        Balance -= amount;
    }
}
```

}

I really need help on handle those errors using exceptions.

Comment: For starters, you should never need to catch a `NullReferenceException`.  Do an explicit null check instead.

Comment: Business rules should be checked and forced by your code, not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to create the requested exception types in your code which we will be using later on.

```
public class InsufficientBalanceException : Exception
{
    // Exception for when a user tries to perform a withdrawal/deposit on an account with an insufficient balance of funds.
    public InsufficientBalanceException() { }

    public InsufficientBalanceException(string message)
    : base(message) { }

    public InsufficientBalanceException(string message, Exception inner)
    : base(message, inner) { }
}

public class InvalidAccountException : Exception
{
    // Exception for when a user is trying to perform an operation on an invalid account.
    public InvalidAccountException() { }

    public InvalidAccountException(string message)
    : base(message) { }

    public InvalidAccountException(string message, Exception inner)
    : base(message, inner) { }
}

public class InvalidNumberOfAccountsException : Exception
{
    // Exception for when a user is trying to create an account beyond the given limit.
    public InvalidNumberOfAccountsException() { }

    public InvalidNumberOfAccountsException(string message)
    : base(message) { }

    public InvalidNumberOfAccountsException(string message, Exception inner)
    : base(message, inner) { }
}
```

Then, you need to specify in what conditions you'll be throwing each one of those exceptions.

Keep in mind you do not want to do this in your entity class since those are designed to be kept as simple as possible.

You'll most likely want to put that logic into some sort of a helper class (and not in the UI as you display in your code). Regardless, your code should look similar to the following:

```
public class AccountHelper
{
    public Account GetAccount(int accountID)
    {
        /* Put some logic in here that retrieves an account object based on the accountID.
         * Return Account object if possible, otherwise return Null */
        return new Account();
    }
    public bool IsValidAccount(int accountID)
    {
        /* Put some logic in here that validates the account.
         * Return True if account exists, otherwise return False */
        return true;
    }
    public bool IsValidAmount(decimal amount)
    {
        /* Put some logic in here that validates the amount.
         * Return True if amount is valid, otherwise return False */
        return amount > 0;
    }
    public bool IsSufficientAmount(Account account, decimal amount)
    {
        /* Put some logic in here that validates the requested amount against the given account.
         * Return True if account balance is valid, otherwise return False */
        if (account == null)
            return false;

        return account.Balance >= amount;
    }
    public void DepositToAccount(int accountID, decimal amount)
    {
        Account account = null;

        if (!IsValidAmount(amount))
            throw new InvalidAmountException();

        if (!IsValidAccount(accountID))
            throw new InvalidAccountException();

        account = GetAccount(accountID);

        account.Deposit(amount);
    }
    public void WithdrawFromAccount(int accountID, decimal amount)
    {
        Account account = null;

        if (!IsValidAmount(amount))
            throw new InvalidAmountException();

        if (!IsValidAccount(accountID))
            throw new InvalidAccountException();

        account = GetAccount(accountID);

        if (!IsSufficientAmount(account, amount))
            throw new InsufficientBalanceException();

        account.Withdraw(amount);
    }
}
```

**Additional Notes:**

1. Your **Accounts** class should be renamed to **Account**, as each
   instance of that object represents one single account.
2. You should be trying to separate your business logic from the UI. It
   is not a good practice to mix things up together as later on you
   might face problems in case changes will have to be made. It will be
   much easier to locate the required lines of code if you keep all of
   your logic in one file and outside the UI.